# Using small caps roman for chapter number with memoir class

Tags: fonts, memoir, small-caps, mathpazo

I want to use small caps roman numbers for chapter numbering using `memoir`. So far I have tried the following:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}

\def\thechapter{{\scshape\roman{chapter}}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpresnum}{\fontfamily{pplx}\selectfont\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\fontfamily{pplx}\selectfont\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftsectionpagefont}{\fontfamily{pplx}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{The number 4 is more than 2}

\section{The number 4 is}
    If I write chapter \ref{anotherChapter} like this is looks oki.
    But the number in the header is a small i not a \textsc{i} and same
    thing in the table of content and the chapter header\dots
\section{More than 4}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur
    tempus facilisis nunc, sit amet suscipit ligula fermentum ac. Ut
    fringilla, elit eget facilisis venenatis, risus massa viverra sem, a
    placerat massa odio a mauris
\chapter{Another chapter}
    \label{anotherChapter}
\end{document}
```

However this is not quite fixing it everywhere. It looks good in section listings in the table of content but not in the chapter listings and it looks good in references to the chapter but not in the chapter nor section headings. What more do I need to do?

**EDIT:** I was trying to make a minimal example but it got a bit too minimal. In my project I am using sans serif for figure captions and after I tried the first version of Lockstep's answer I got this:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{helvet}

\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{%
\fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont
\textsc{\roman{chapter}}%
\fontfamily{pplj}\selectfont
}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\fontfamily{pplj}\selectfont\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftsectionpagefont}{\fontfamily{pplj}\selectfont}
\captionnamefont{\sffamily\scshape\small}
\captiontitlefont{\sffamily\small}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{The number 4 is more than 2}

\section{The number 4 is}
    If I write chapter \ref{anotherChapter} like this is
    looks oki.
    But the number in the header is a small i not a \textsc{i} and same
    thing in the table of content and the chapter header\dots
    \begin{figure}
        \caption{Lorem ipsum}
        \center \LARGE LOREM IPSUM
    \end{figure}
\section{More than 4}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur
    tempus facilisis nunc, sit amet suscipit ligula fermentum ac. Ut
    fringilla, elit eget facilisis venenatis, risus massa viverra sem, a
    placerat massa odio a mauris
\chapter{Another chapter}
    \label{anotherChapter}
\end{document}
```

Notice that the font for the number in the figure caption now is the wrong one.

Answer (score 2):

The `osf` option of `mathpazo` switches to the `pplj` font family to display oldstyle figures -- but `pplj` (contrary to `ppl`) does not feature bold small caps, and so your roman numerals are simply displayed in bold. Because you need a combination of bold small caps and bold oldstyle figures for things like "[Section] i.1", the solution is to switch to `ppl` and back to `pplj` within the definition of `\thechapter`. (You may also want to switch to `pplj` instead of `pplx` for ToC page numbers.)

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{%
  \ifdefstring{\f@family}{phv}{%
    \textsc{\roman{chapter}}%
  }{%
    \fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont
    \textsc{\roman{chapter}}%
    \fontfamily{pplj}\selectfont
  }%
}
\makeatother
\captionnamefont{\sffamily\scshape\small}
\captiontitlefont{\sffamily\small}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{The number 4 is more than 2}

\section{The number 4 is}
    If I write chapter \ref{anotherChapter} like this is
    looks oki.
    But the number in the header is a small i not a \textsc{i} and same
    thing in the table of content and the chapter header\dots
    \begin{figure}
        \caption{Lorem ipsum}
        \center \LARGE LOREM IPSUM
    \end{figure}
\section{More than 4}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur
    tempus facilisis nunc, sit amet suscipit ligula fermentum ac. Ut
    fringilla, elit eget facilisis venenatis, risus massa viverra sem, a
    placerat massa odio a mauris
\chapter{Another chapter}
    \label{anotherChapter}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: Example updated in order to switch only to `ppl` if the current font family is `pplj`. The additional code is based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14377/how-can-i-test-for-the-current-font/14382#14382) answer from Mike Renfro; for some reason (expansion?) I had to replace the `ifthen` package with `etoolbox` to make it work.

EDIT 2: I don't know why my test for `pplj` partially fails. Anyhow, a test for `phv` (Helvetica) succeeds. :-)

Comment: @lockstep: Actually the reason I started to mess around was that I thought the old style numbers for page numbers looked a bit unorganized. I am not sure if people normally stay with old style numbers everywhere or if they usually mix but I thought the old style numbers gave a unorganized impression when used for those page numbers so I thought I should print both variants on paper and give it a good think-over...

Comment: @jonalv: Also, don't let yourself fool by the size of the small caps -- they are still somewhat larger than oldstyle nums.

Comment: @lockstep: Hm good point. It's still better though, or do you have any suggestions on that topic? I mean they don't look like screaming the way full caps do...

Comment: @lockstep Hm I ran into some further problem. I am using another font for figure captions and now I get the chapter number of the figures written with the wrong font...

Comment: @jonalv: Please give more specific information.

Comment: @jonalv: Never mind ... I saw your follow-up question and understand the problem now. Martin Scharrer's and Mike Renfro's answer are appropriate complements to my hackery.

Comment: @lockstep: Hm I get:
! Argument of \@secondoftwo has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.2 ...textsc {i}}}The number 4 is more than 2}{2}
                                                  
?

Also you set the font back to pplj at the end of the command. Why is this? This is going to cause similar problems, no?

Comment: @jonalv: Dang -- I get no error, but also not the desired effect. Must have been blind. I'll try again, but can't promise anything.

Comment: @lockstep Just for clarity, neither your updated example runs on my machine. (after Edit 2)