# How to get currently used math font? Or: How to ensure use of math font in pgfplots axis labels and ticks even if overwritten by text string?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, fonts

**Preface:**

An axis plotted with [pgfplots](/questions/tagged/pgfplots) is usually using the current math font for its ticklabels. But if they are overwritten by e.g. `xticklabels={-8,-6,...,8}` then the current text font is used. Also an axis label `ylabel={Y}` would be in text font unless put explicitly in math mode `ylabel={$Y$}`. However it would be nice, if  one hadn't to do so.

**Question:**

I'm aiming to ensure that **pgfplots always uses the current math font**. But please assume that the classic font commands like `\rmfamily` are screwed up by the corporate design I'm supposed to use, e.g. assume: `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{\sfdefault}`

It works if I explicitly define a font

```
\newcommand{\pgfmathfont}{\fontfamily{pxfonts}\selectfont}
```

and pass it to pgfplots together with `assume math mode=true`:

```
\begin{axis}[
font = \pgfmathfont, 
tick label style={/pgf/number format/assume math mode=true}
]
```

But it requires that I insert the name of the current math font. How can I do that automatically? **How to get the currently used math font to insert it into the macro?**

---

### MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{pxfonts}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

% screwed up by Corporate Design
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{\sfdefault}

% I'd like this line to be generic!
\newcommand{\pgfmathfont}{\fontfamily{pxfonts}\selectfont}
%           put current math font here   X

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

This is a basic equation:   
\[ x + y = 42\]

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
%   font = \rmfamily, % makes no sense here
    font = \pgfmathfont, 
    xlabel={$x$-label: I want to be in math font!},
    ylabel={Y},
    xtick={-4,-3,...,4},
    xticklabels={-8,-6,...,8},
%   xticklabels={$-8$,$-6$,...,$8$}, % does not work
    tick label style={/pgf/number format/assume math mode=true}
    ]

    \addplot {x^2};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

**Everything related to [fontspec](/questions/tagged/fontspec) is no option at all!**

Thank you!

Comment: Well it can't be automatically in math mode for a good reason because labels are 99% of the time plain text. When you have the explicit labels you can `xticklabels={$-8$,$-6$,$...$,$8$}` to make it work. (notice the dollar signs around the ellipsis...)

Comment: This is a nice hint -> `$...$`! Well I'm aware that if in my example above probably the text shape of *pfxonts* is used and not the math shape. But in my above example pgfplots uses `pxfonts` by default, until the labels are overwritten, then it changes to the beamer font used for text. So in this particular case it should be possible to determine what font is loaded (if not pxfonts) which then is used by pgfplots and should be used also in the ` font = ... ` key?

Comment: Does this answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14378/69445 help you?

Comment: @cryingshadow It looks promision, but then I'd expect something like `\newcommand{\pgfmathfont}{\fontfamily{\the\font}\selectfont}` to work, but I get a `Missing \endcsname inserted. \end{frame}` error. Any idea on that? Coudl you may try make it an answer for the MWE?

Comment: @thewaywewalk Sorry, I also don't know why this does not work. However, you already have good answers. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ticklabels could be calculated from the ticks using

```
xticklabel={\pgfmathparse{2*\tick}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}
```

But if you really want to use `tick label style={/pgf/number format/assume math mode=true}` you have to surround `\pgfmathprintnumber{}` by `$...$`. Note that `assume math mode=true` should only be used if you are sure that math mode is active. From the pgfmanual: " ... the final number is typeset as-is, no further checking is performed."

```
xticklabel={\pgfmathparse{2*\tick}$\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}$},
tick label style={/pgf/number format/assume math mode=true}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}% as suggested by @egreg
\usepackage{pgfplots}

% screwed up by Corporate Design
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
This is a basic equation:   
\[ x + y = 42\]
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    font = \rmfamily,
    xlabel={$x$-label: I want to be in math font!},
    ylabel={Y},
    xtick={-4,-3,...,4},
    xticklabel={\pgfmathparse{2*\tick}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}},
    ]
    \addplot {x^2};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Another possibility is

```
xticklabels={$-8$,$-6$,$...$,$8$}
```

as suggested by @percusse in a comment to your question. Note that `$...$` is  used.

---

If the tick labels can not be calculated from the tick values you can define an array

```
\def\myxticklabels{{1.9, 7, 42, 5, 5, 6, 8, 5, 0.720}}
```

and use

```
xticklabel={\pgfmathparse{\myxticklabels[\ticknum]}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}},
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}% as suggested by @egreg
\usepackage{pgfplots}

% screwed up by Corporate Design
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
This is a basic equation:
\[ x + y = 42\]
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\myxticklabels{{1.9, 7, 42, 5, 5, 6, 8, 5, 0.720}}
    \begin{axis}[
    font = \rmfamily,
    xlabel={$x$-label: I want to be in math font!},
    ylabel={Y},
    xtick={-4,-3,...,4},
    xticklabel={\pgfmathparse{\myxticklabels[\ticknum]}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}},
    /pgf/number format/use comma
    ]
    \addplot {x^2};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great solution If you have a constant factor to multiply the ticks with, should work in most of my cases! But would it be also a possible to pass an array to `\pgfmathparse` ? e.g: `\pgfmathparse{ {1, 7, 42, 5}  }`

Comment: @thewaywalk See my updated answer.

Comment: I finally used your approach as it takes `\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,use comma}` into account, but put it into the `\pgfplotsset` as suggested by [egreg](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/281512/36835). Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Define a new style:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

% screwed up by Corporate Design
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{\sfdefault}

\pgfplotsset{
  typeset ticklabels as math/.style={
    /pgfplots/typeset ticklabel/.code={$##1$},
  },
}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

This is a basic equation:   
\[ x + y = -8\]

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xlabel={$x$-label: I want to be in math font!},
    ylabel={Y},
    xtick={-4,-3,...,4},
    xticklabels={-8,-6,...,8},
    typeset ticklabels as math,
    tick label style={/pgf/number format/assume math mode=true}
    ]

    \addplot {x^2};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the combination `newpxtext` with `newpxmath` should be preferred to `pxfonts`, because it cures some drawbacks from the unmaintained older package.

Comment: ìt is a nice solution for the ticklabels. But for the x- and y-labels it would still require some quirky things like `xlabel={$t_0 ~\text{in}~ \si{\second}$} `. or in case you could define similary `typeset labels as math` one would need `xlabel={t ~\text{in}~ \si{\second}} `. But the aim would be to use juse `xlabel={$t_0$  in \si{\second}} `

Comment: I finally used a combination of both answers, your idea with the new style, but the  `ticklabel/.code={...}` filled with [esdd's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/281521/36835) as it takes `\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,use comma}` into account. Thank you!

Comment: Very elegant answer ! It seems this style option `typeset ticklabel/.code={}` is not in the `pgfplots` manual. Do you confirm ? Where did you find it if you do not mind ?

Comment: @BambOo I don't remember.