# Change thousands separator in pfgplots' ticklabels to space

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, numbering, nomenclature

I am sure that I am repeating an old question, but I couldn't find it in the Tex Exchange browser.

I am using french mathematics nomenclature and thousand separation is a space like this `1 000` and not by a coma `1,000` (that means `1` in french). The `pgfplots` package make appear numbers in the thousand separation as english typesetting and I want to change it.

Illustration :

[image]

Comment: Try add into axis option `ticks={style={/pgf/number format/set thousands separator={\,}}},`.

Comment: In your axis labels, n and r should probably be replaced by $n$ and $r$, respectively.

Comment: yes @pluton, I'm going to change it

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the following key:

```
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={\,}}
```

### Full MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={\,}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot {100*x^2};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you're just changing one key, you can use

```
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/1000 sep={\,}}
```

as mentioned by Jake in the comments.

---

In case you're often switching languages with its various number formats you'll probably use the **siunitx** package to do so in text. To synchronize your siunitx settings with the ticklabels, you could use:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{group-digits=true,
         group-four-digits=true,
         group-separator = {\,},
         output-decimal-marker = {,}}

\pgfplotsset{
  siunitxlabels/.style={
    /pgfplots/typeset ticklabel/.code={\pgfmathparse{\tick}$\num[zero-decimal-to-integer]{\pgfmathresult}$},
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[siunitxlabels
    ]
    \addplot {100*x^2};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(inspired by answers to [**this question**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281503/how-to-get-currently-used-math-font-or-how-to-ensure-use-of-math-font-in-pgfpl))