# Minion's footnotefigures mistakenly appear in non-roman text formats

Tags: footnotes, minionpro

The `MinionPro` package offers the option `footnotefigures`. When active, special glyphs are used for footnotes, which look a bit thicker than normal numbers.

[image]

This option is defined as

```
\DeclareOption{footnotefigures}{%
\def\@makefnmark{%
\begingroup
\normalfont
\fontfamily{MinionPro-Extra}\fontencoding{U}\selectfont
\@thefnmark
\endgroup}}
```

The problem with this option is that overwrites the design for all text environments, which is of course is not really appealing. So is there way to use the special footnote glyphs without changing the appearance of footnotes in e.g.  serif text?

[image]

### MWE

```
\documentclass{scrbook}    
\usepackage{MinionPro}    
\makeatletter
\def\@makefnmark{%
\begingroup
\normalfont
\fontfamily{MinionPro-Extra}\fontencoding{U}\selectfont
\@thefnmark
\endgroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}    
Some more\footnote{Second footnote} text.

\textsf{Some more\footnote{Second footnote} text.}

\texttt{Some more\footnote{Second footnote} text.}    
\end{document}
```

### Edit

Based on this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14382/7306) I tried to implement code to detect whether MinionPro is currently the active font, but without success. The if condition never seems to be true.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{MinionPro}

\def\@makefnmark{%
\begingroup%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\f@family{}}{MinionPro-OsF}}%
    {\f@family\normalfont\fontfamily{MinionPro-Extra}\fontencoding{U}\selectfont\@thefnmark}%
    {\f@family\textsuperscript{\@thefnmark}}%
\endgroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Some more\footnote{Second footnote} text.

\textsf{Some more\footnote{Second footnote} text.}

\texttt{Some more\footnote{Second footnote} text.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't you want them to be used in serif text? Maybe not in non-serif text, but aren't they intended for serif?

Comment: @cfr I want them to used only when MinionPro is the current font just as in your second example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Update

This version deals with other families of MinionPro with different names (one for each style of figures), per a request in the comments without relying on nesting `\if...\fi` loops.

One way to do this is to compare the current font family with a comma-separated list of qualifying families. Various package implement this kind of facility. Here, I rely on an unholy mix of **expl3** and lower-level `@` stuff.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{MinionPro,expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_maetra_fontfamily_tl
\clist_const:Nn \c_maetra_MPs_clist { MinionPro-OsF, MinionPro-TOsF, MinionPro-LF, MinionPro-TLF }
\makeatletter
\let\@makefnmarkorig\@makefnmark
\def\@makefnmark{%
  \group_begin:
    \tl_set:Nx \l_maetra_fontfamily_tl { \f@family }
    \clist_if_in:NVTF \c_maetra_MPs_clist \l_maetra_fontfamily_tl
    {
      \normalfont
      \fontfamily{MinionPro-Extra}\fontencoding{U}\selectfont
      \@thefnmark
    }
    {
      \textsuperscript{ \@thefnmark }
    }
  \group_end:
}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Some more\footnote{Second footnote} text.
0123456789

\fontfamily{MinionPro-TOsF}\selectfont
Some more\footnote{Second footnote} text.
0123456789

\fontfamily{MinionPro-LF}\selectfont
Some more\footnote{Second footnote} text.
0123456789

\fontfamily{MinionPro-TLF}\selectfont
Some more\footnote{Second footnote} text.
0123456789

\textsf{Some more\footnote{Second footnote} text.}

\texttt{Some more\footnote{Second footnote} text.}
\end{document}
```

[image: variations on a footnote theme]

## Original (*sans* **expl3**)

Do you want something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{MinionPro}
\makeatletter
\let\@makefnmarkorig\@makefnmark
\def\@makefnmark{%
  \begingroup
    \edef\tempa{\f@family}%
    \edef\tempb{MinionPro-OsF}%
    \ifx\tempa\tempb
      \normalfont
      \fontfamily{MinionPro-Extra}\fontencoding{U}\selectfont
    \@thefnmark
    \else
      \@makefnmarkorig
    \fi
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Some more\footnote{Second footnote} text.

\textsf{Some more\footnote{Second footnote} text.}

\texttt{Some more\footnote{Second footnote} text.}
\end{document}
```

[image: footnote mark variations]

Note that the use of serifs for footnote markers is default and not a result of **MinionPro**:

[image: default]

If you don't want that, you might prefer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{MinionPro}
\makeatletter
\let\@makefnmarkorig\@makefnmark
\def\@makefnmark{%
  \begingroup
    \edef\tempa{\f@family}%
    \edef\tempb{MinionPro-OsF}%
    \ifx\tempa\tempb
      \normalfont
      \fontfamily{MinionPro-Extra}\fontencoding{U}\selectfont
      \@thefnmark
    \else
    \textsuperscript{\@thefnmark}%
    \fi
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Some more\footnote{Second footnote} text.

\textsf{Some more\footnote{Second footnote} text.}

\texttt{Some more\footnote{Second footnote} text.}
\end{document}
```

[image: non-default footnote variations]

Comment: You are right, the article class always uses serifs for footnote markers, but scrbook does not it changes to the current text format which imho is the better choice.

Comment: Is there an better way to detect for MinionPro-TOsF, MinionPro-LF, MinionPro-TLF as well than using 3 additional if else conditions?

Comment: You can use a cases construction, maybe? That would be much tidier.

Comment: @maetra Please see edit.