# What is the exact font-family name when using XeLaTeX/fontspec?

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, xecjk

I'm now using XeLaTeX and fontspec(also uses xeCJK). I use

```
\setmainfont{Georgia}
```

to set my default English font, and

```
\setCJKmainfont{cwTeX Q Ming}
```

to set my default Chinese font.

However, if I want to use the commands, such like `\DeclareSymbolFont {<sym-font-name>} {<encoding>} {<family>} {<series>} {<shape>}`, and assign the current font family I'm using. What name of the *family* should I fill into? (Also, what's the proper *font-encoding*? OT1?) I'd looked up the fontspec document, but didn't find the solution.

Comment: (for reference, you can use `\commandtoselectthefont \expandafter\string\the\font` to view the internal font name https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14377/how-can-i-test-for-the-current-font)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The internal font family name is not usable, it contains a number which can change. But you can give your font a family name (if your fontspec is not too old). The encoding with a current fontspec/LaTeX is TU, in older versions EU1.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Georgia}[NFSSFamily=Georgia]

\begin{document}
blblb \fontfamily{Georgia}\fontencoding{TU}\selectfont blblb

\end{document}
```

Comment: Got it!! The key is `NFSSFamily`!!! Thanks!