# Is there a way to do a pair command?

Tags: fonts, macros

I want to get the name of the fonts in the document while I write my document.

At the moment I am alright with

```
\newcommand{\FntNmeTitleA}{Felix Titling Regular}
\newfontfamily\FontTitleA[LetterSpace=4.5]{Felix Titling}

\FontTitleA This Text is written in \FntNmeTitleA!
```

But that sucks if I have a lot fonts and want to get the current name. Is there a way like known in many programming languages:

```
\FontTitleA This Text is written in \FontTitleA.name!
```

Cheers

Comment: Is this useful? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14377/how-can-i-test-for-the-current-font

Comment: Please provide a complete example. I assume you are using `fontspec`, but even this isn't guaranteed from the paltry fragements you've posted. As @RobtA says, with traditional typesetting, `\f@family` gives the current family. Other aspects of the current font are stored similarly, so you can retrieve and test them or whatever. (`nfssext-cfr.sty` does this extensively.)

Answer (score 2):

In the standard case, the current font information is stored in a series of internal macros beginning with `\f@`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
  encoding \f@encoding\par
  family \f@family\par
  series \f@series\par
  shape \f@shape\par
  size \f@size\par
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

Compiled with pdfLaTeX:

[image: font information]

Compiled with LuaLaTeX or (after a while) XeLaTeX:

[image: Unicode font information]

With a custom font in LuaLaTeX, using `fontspec`:

[image: custom font]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\sylfaen{Sylfaen}
\begin{document}
\sylfaen
\makeatletter
  encoding \f@encoding\par
  family \f@family\par
  series \f@series\par
  shape \f@shape\par
  size \f@size\par
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

Comment: In the above example, with fontspec, where the font is Sylfaen(0), the (0) indicates that this is the first (usually, main) instance of how the font is used. If you do `\newfontfamily\somefont{Sylfaen}` with the same font, then `{\somefont text}` puts the text in Sylfaen(1). And so forth. So, if you want to extract only the font name, you can use a macro from the xstring package to get rid of the parenthesized number.

Comment: @RobtA You don't really need the `xstring` package for that, though.

Comment: Thank you. Any idea how it could be possible to save that in a file or in the footnotes?

Comment: I tried it like this: `%[Praemble]
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \LtrFnt
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\setLtrFnt}{o}
{
 \tl_gset:Nn \LtrFnt 
 {\expandafter\textttup\expandafter{\expandafter\string\the\font}}
 %{\f@family \f@series \f@shape }
}
\makeatother
\NewDocumentCommand{\getLtrFnt}{}{%
 \tl_use:N \LtrFnt%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
 \rmfamily{\setHdFnt} Hello World!\footnote{\ttfamily%
 Text used in main document: \getLtrFnt\\
\end{document}`