# \the\font produces no output

Tags: fonts

According to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14378/21685),

> You can access the current font using the `\font` command, i.e. using `\the\font` which expand to e.g. `\OT1/cmr/m/n/10` for the normal *Computer Modern* font.

Then why does the following LaTeX manuscript, when compiled with pdfTeX (TeXLive 2017), produce no pdf file?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\the\font
\end{documen‌​t}
```

Comment: `\the\font` doesn't produce any output; it has never.

Comment: @egreg: Then what does it mean that `\the\font` expands to `/OT1/cmr/m/n/10`? And how can I output the current font?

Comment: It expands to the _command_  `\OT1/cmr/m/n/10` which selects that font not to the verbatim text `\OT1/cmr/m/n/10`

Comment: in plain tex it is as if it said `\the\font` expands to `\rm`  it does not mean it makes the letters backslash r m  it means it expands to the command `\rm` which selects a roman font

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Oh, I see. So how can I output the current font?

Comment: `\expandafter\meaning\the\font`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: `\expandafter\meaning\the\font` yields, for example, `select font cmtt10`, where `cmtt10` is the external (that is, filesystem’s) name of the font; to get something of the form `\OT1/cmtt/m/n/10`, say, I’d rather suggest `\expandafter\string\the\font`.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti well yes true that but possibly the external font name was really what the OP was after, egreg's `\fontname` suggestion comes to more or less the same thing too.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I just thought it was something worth mentioning in a comment; indeed, the OP [has subsequently made it clear](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376351/the-font-produces-no-output?noredirect=1#comment931695_376354) that (s)he was after something still different.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Do I understand correctly that the name of the command `\OT1/cmr/m/n/10` is 'OT1/cmr/m/n/10', i.e. the slash characters are part of the command's *name*?

Comment: Yes that is the way latex generates csnames

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I originally thought the command name was simply `\OT1` and the rest was a list of delimited arguments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turned out that the OP’s preference goes to `\expandafter\string\the\font`.

The following (compilable) example compares three approaches that have been proposed:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}



\begin{document}

Compare
\begin{center}
    \expandafter\meaning\the\font
\end{center}
with
\begin{center}
    \expandafter\string\the\font
\end{center}
and with
\begin{center}
    \fontname\font
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image: Output of the code]

---

## Addendum

Let me add a few remark, just to clarify a couple of points.

As I already observed in a comment, in the so-called *New Font Selection Scheme* (NFSS), which is part of LaTeX2e, the fact that the control sequence for selecting a font has the form

```
\<encoding>/<family>/<series>/<shape>/<size>
```

is *not* a “happy incident”, but a precise design principle on which the NFSS itself relies heavily.

Simply think of how a typical “low level” font selection like

```
\fontfamily{cmdh}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}%
\selectfont
```

works: first, the three declarations in the first line set the corresponding internal macros `\f@family`, `\f@series`, and `\f@shape`; then, the `\selectfont` command uses the updated values to build, and subsequently invoke, the appropriate “font-selecting” control sequence.  Indeed, the LaTeX2e kernel defines `\fontfamily`, `\fontseries`, and `\fontshape` as follows:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\fontfamily[1]{\edef\f@family{#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\fontseries[1]{\edef\f@series{#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\fontshape [1]{\edef\f@shape{#1}}
```

`\fontencoding` and `\fontsize` are a bit more complicated, but among the other things they do they set, in a similar way, the internal macros `\f@encoding` and `\f@size`.  On the other hand, the definition of `\selectfont` is

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\selectfont
        {%
    \ifx\f@linespread\baselinestretch \else
      \set@fontsize\baselinestretch\f@size\f@baselineskip \fi
    \xdef\font@name{%
      \csname\curr@fontshape/\f@size\endcsname}%
    \pickup@font
    \font@name
    \size@update
    \enc@update
    }
```

The lines that are relevant to our discussion are

```
    \xdef\font@name{%
      \csname\curr@fontshape/\f@size\endcsname}%
    \pickup@font
    \font@name
```

As you can see, the macro `\font@name` is made to expand to a control sequence whose name is obtained by the concatenation of the full expansion of `\curr@fontshape`, a `/`, and the full expansion of `\f@size`; since `\curr@fontshape` is (statically) defined as

```
\def\curr@fontshape{\f@encoding/\f@family/\f@series/\f@shape}
```

and since this definition gets *fully* expanded, we see that this process indeed yields a control sequence of the form

```
\T1/cmdh/m/n/10
```

(for example).  The `\pickup@font` macro ensures that this control name is defined and that it loads the correct external font (this is where the real “hard work” takes place!), after which the font selector that has just been constructed is invoked by executing `\font@name`.

We can add that `\size@update` and `\enc@update` are simply “hooks” where actions that need to be executed when the font size and/or encoding, respectively, have changed can be stored, and that the two lines of code that mention `\baselinestretch` take into account the possibility that the user has directly modified this obsolete LaTeX2.09 style parameter.

All that said, and following [a suggestion from the OP](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376351/the-font-produces-no-output/376399#comment931803_376399), we can supplement our original example with a couple of other methods to obtain information about the current font:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}



\begin{document}

Compare
\begin{center}
    \expandafter\meaning\the\font
\end{center}
with
\begin{center}
    \expandafter\string\the\font
\end{center}
and with
\begin{center}
    \fontname\font
\end{center}
Other methods that use internal commands follow.

\makeatletter

Taking font components apart:
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        Encoding: & \f@encoding  \\
        Family:   & \f@family    \\
        Series:   & \f@series    \\
        Shape:    & \f@shape     \\
        Size:     & \f@size
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
All in a row:
\begin{center}
    \selectfont % needed in order to get "\font@name" in sync
    \expandafter\string\font@name
\end{center}

\makeatother

\end{document}
```

The corresponding output is:

[image: Output of the second code example]

Comment: Sorry, I deleted the comment that you linked to at the beginning of your answer before I realized that you had posted an answer. The reason why I deleted it was that I realized (please correct me if I'm wrong) that it is a happy accident that the name of the command for switching to the *Computer Modern* font contains the entire font specifications (i.e encoding, family, series, shape, and size), but it can happen for some other font that not all this information will be encapsulated in the switching command's name, in which case the method you described won't give me the information I desire.

Comment: You might as well add to your answer the *fourth* method proposed by me (copied from Mike Renfro) in the comment to egreg's reply... (which is the most reliably informative method of them all)

Comment: Or maybe the method I described in the comment to egreg's answer is information-equivalent to your method in that what the `\f@...` macros do is simply parse the font name string and break it down to its components?

Comment: @Evan  the other direction: latex constructs  the csname from the encoding, family, shape,  etc

Comment: @EvanAad: “it is a happy accident that the name of the command for switching to [a] font contains the entire font specifications”.  For fonts selected through the NFSS, it is not a “happy incident”, it is so by design: indeed, the LaTeX2e kernel provides macros *both* for extracting the encoding, family, etc. from the font selector (_i.e._, the csname) *and* for assembling a font selector from the separate specifications.  Perhaps you are referring to fonts that are not selected through the NFSS; but in that case, do the macros `\f@encoding`, `\f@family`, etc. still make sense?

Answer (score 5):

The usage of `\the\font` is to define a control sequence that expands to the current font selector.

So `\edef\thisfont{\the\font}` would make `\thisfont` expand to, say, `\tenrm`.

Used by itself it just produces the font selector, hence no output.

You may also do

```
\expandafter\let\expandafter\thisfont\the\font
```

and `\thisfont` would become equivalent to the font selector for the current font.

Maybe you were meaning `\fontname\font`, that expands to the name of the TFM file corresponding to the current font.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, after some experimenting based on [Mike Renfro's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14382/21685) I've found out what I was after, namely the following code (to be inserted inside the body of a LaTeX document): `\makeatletter encoding:\f@encoding{},family:\f@family{},series:\f@series{},shape:\f@shape{},size:\f@size{}\makeatother`.