# Print out all relevant document information. (Maybe a package?)

Tags: macros, packages, printing, output, document-configuration

I starting to make a table which print out all for me relevant document information in one table like

- actual paper width,
- count of words,
- actual font size
- actual font type
- ...

Is there maybe a package available for this? Or anyone know where I can find the missing commands (print out count fo words, print out current font, current font size)

```
\begin{table}[]
\footnotesize
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll}  
\toprule
Feature & Value\\
\midrule
actual paper width in [cm] &  \printinunitsof{cm}\prntlen{\textwidth}  \\
actual font size & <??> \\   \bottomrule 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: The current font size is stored in `\f@size` (this is not a length but a macro storing the size in pt you can access it with either `\makeatletter\f@size\makeatother` or `\csname f@size\endcsname`.).

Comment: You can also access the paper width, but the word count [seems to require additional software](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/534/121799).

Comment: And (if you didn't know yet), there are the dimensions `\textheight`, `\paperheight`, `\paperwidth`, `\marginparwidth`, ... The [wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout) has a bit of information about all the lengths related to page layout.

Comment: And this question might be of interest: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14377/how-can-i-test-for-the-current-font

Comment: the count of words does not really fit there, all the other things are tex defined lengths, but tex has no idea about the number of words in the docuemnt

Comment: many thanks @skillmon there are some features i was not thinking about

Answer (score 1):

I made a listing in a tabular environment with some information which are helpful for me. Maybe this can help someone else:

```
\documentclass {scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{layouts}
\usepackage{lmodern}

%//Colour definitions\\%
\newcommand{\fillOne}{green!35!black}
\newcommand{\fillTwo}{black!10}
\newcommand{\fillThree}{red!10!}
\newcommand{\fillFour}{black!10!blue}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}} 

% display some document properties
\edef\defaultfont{\fontname\font}  
\edef\defaultsize{\csname f@size\endcsname}  
\newcommand{\currentfont}{\fontname\font}
\newcommand{\currentsize}{\csname f@size\endcsname}


\begin{document}

\newcommand{\printProperties}
{
\newlength{\freewidth}
\begin{table}[]
\footnotesize
\setlength{\freewidth}{\dimexpr\textwidth-6\tabcolsep}
\begin{tabular}{L{.7\freewidth}L{.2\freewidth}L{.10\freewidth}}   
\toprule
Feature & Value \\
\midrule
PaperWidth in [cm]& \printinunitsof{cm}\prntlen{\paperwidth}\\
PaperHeight in [cm]& \printinunitsof{cm}\prntlen{\paperheight}\\
TextWidth in [cm] &  \printinunitsof{cm}\prntlen{\textwidth}  \\
TextHeight in [cm] & \printinunitsof{cm}\prntlen{\textheight}\\
\midrule
MarginParSep in [cm] & \printinunitsof{cm}\prntlen{\marginparsep}\\
MarginParWidth in [cm] & \printinunitsof{cm}\prntlen{\marginparwidth}\\
FootSkip in [cm]& \printinunitsof{cm}\prntlen{\footskip}\\
\midrule
Default Font &  \defaultfont \\
Default Size   & \defaultsize \\
Current Font &  \currentfont \\
Current Size &  \currentsize \\
\midrule
Colour1 & \fillOne & \begin{tikzpicture} \draw[fill=\fillOne, draw=none] (0,0) rectangle (1,.2); \end{tikzpicture}\\
Colour2 & \fillTwo & \begin{tikzpicture} \draw[fill=\fillTwo, draw=none] (0,0) rectangle (1,.2); \end{tikzpicture}\\
Colour3 & \fillThree & \begin{tikzpicture} \draw[fill=\fillThree, draw=none] (0,0) rectangle (1,.2); \end{tikzpicture}\\
Colour4 & \fillFour & \begin{tikzpicture} \draw[fill=\fillFour, draw=none] (0,0) rectangle (1,.2); \end{tikzpicture}\\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
}

\printProperties

\end{document}
```

Which results in:

[image]